# On Noise Contrastive Estimation, replace noise distribution with difficult examples

Tags: distribution

In noise contrastive estimation, we learn a binary classifier to classify noise from the true distribution.

**The problem I'm trying to solve** has discrete input variables yet it's intractable to sum over. I want to approximate the true distribution by using NCE.

**The Question is:** is it okay to draw difficult examples (noise samples)
 the model is likely to misclassify, instead of sampling naive noise examples.

**From a manifold perspective** I want to learn the structure of the manifold, I know for each data point a group of data points that are for sure out of the manifold.
So I directly replace the noise distribution by this (difficult examples distribution) is still valid? Am I still doing NCE?